# How to append Jobject to the Jarray of Jproperty?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am creating new Jobject as,

```
var testresult = new JObject(new JProperty("Name", "John"),
                    new JProperty("Nums", new JArray()));
```

Result is:

```
{
  "Name": "John",
  "Nums": []
}
```

And I am trying to add another JObject inside of the JArray of Jproperty "Nums".

```
{
      "Name": "John",
      "Nums": [{"tl1": "tr1"}, {"tl2": "tr2"}]
 }
```

I have tried testresult.Property.Add , AddAfterSelf style but I think my main problem is I cannot access the right side of JProperty "Nums". What can I try or look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create all in one line

```
var testresult = new JObject(new JProperty("Name", "John"), new JProperty("Nums", new JArray(
new JObject(new JProperty("tl1", "tr1") ),new JObject(new JProperty("tl2", "tr2") ))));
```

or if you want to add new items later, you can do it in one line too

```
testresult["Nums"]=new JArray(new JObject(new JProperty("tl1", "tr1") ), 
new JObject(new JProperty("tl2", "tr2")));
```

or if you want to add an array of  new items to an exising array, you can use Merge

```
((JArray) testresult["Nums"]).Merge(new JArray(new JObject(new JProperty("tl1", "tr1")), new JObject(new JProperty("tl2", "tr2"))));
```

or Add if you want to add one more item to array

```
((JArray) testresult["Nums"]).Add( new JObject(new JProperty("tl1", "tr1")));
```

result

```
{
  "Name": "John",
  "Nums": [
    {
      "tl1": "tr1"
    },
    {
      "tl2": "tr2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either initialize the `JArray` or use `Add`:

```
        JArray arr = new JArray()
        {
            new JObject()
            {
                new JProperty("tl1", "tr1")
            }
        };
        
        arr.Add(new JObject()
        {
            new JProperty("tl2", "tr2")
        });

        JObject obj = new JObject()
        {
            new JProperty("Name", "John"),
            new JProperty("Nums", arr)
        };

        Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

which produces:

```
{
   "Name": "John",
   "Nums": [
        {
          "tl1": "tr1"
        },
        {
          "tl2": "tr2"
        }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JArray` has an `Add` method. You can access the `JArray` like so:

```
JArray myArray = (JArray)testresult["Nums"];
myArray.Add(new JObject(new JProperty("tl1", "tr1")));
```

I've assumed the object should be `{"tl1":"tr1"}` since `{"tl1", "tr1"}` isn't a valid JSON object.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/HDQTK88727)